# Plotting the Continuous Wavelet Transform of a signal using db2 in julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to draw a heatmap of my signal passed through a CWT using db2.  The following does not plot a heatmap, just a blank chart.

```
using ContinuousWavelets

c = wavelet(cDb2, β = 2, extraOctaves = -0)
res = ContinuousWavelets.cwt(signal, c)

heatmap(res, xlabel= "time index", ylabel="frequency index", colorbar=false)
```

Comment: are the values flat or are they just plotted flat?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the range of values, potentially also element type. you say it looks "blank", i.e. all values appear to be the same, and either black or white or transparent. also, `signal` is undefined. [mre] please.